# Unable to install Key Manager on WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm attempting to install the Key Manager feature on a WSO2 Identity Server 5.0.0 instance, following the directions at https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Configuring+WSO2+Identity+Server+as+the+Key+Manager.

However after adding the repository and attempting to install the feature I get:

> Your original install request has been modified. org.wso2.carbon.event.server.feature.group-4.2.1 will be ignored because it is already installed. org.wso2.carbon.security.mgt.server.feature.group-4.2.5 will be ignored because a newer version is already installed. org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.common.feature.group-4.2.3 is already present because other installed software requires it. It will be added to the installed software list. org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.server.feature.group-4.2.2 is already installed, so an update will be performed instead. org.wso2.carbon.identity.self.registration.server.feature.group-4.2.2 will be ignored because it is already installed. org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.server.feature.group-4.2.2 will be ignored because a newer version is already installed. org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.feature.group-4.2.3 is already installed, so an update will be performed instead. org.wso2.carbon.event.common.feature.group-4.2.0 is already present because other installed software requires it. It will be added to the installed software list. org.wso2.carbon.registry.contentsearch.feature.group-4.2.1 is already installed, so an update will be performed instead. Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency. Software being installed: Trusted Identity Provider Management Feature 4.2.4 (org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.feature.group 4.2.4) Software currently installed: WSO2 Stratos - Common Composite Feature 2.2.2 (org.wso2.carbon.stratos.common.feature.group 2.2.2) Only one of the following can be installed at once: WSO2 Stratos - Common Core Feature 2.2.0 (org.wso2.carbon.stratos.common.server.feature.jar 2.2.0) WSO2 Stratos - Common Core Feature 2.3.0 (org.wso2.carbon.stratos.common.server.feature.jar 2.3.0) WSO2 Stratos - Common Core Feature 2.2.1 (org.wso2.carbon.stratos.common.server.feature.jar 2.2.1) WSO2 Stratos - Common Core Feature 2.2.2 (org.wso2.carbon.stratos.common.server.feature.jar 2.2.2) Cannot satisfy dependency: From: Trusted Identity Provider Management Feature 4.2.4 (org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.feature.group 4.2.4) To: org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.server.feature.group [4.2.4] Cannot satisfy dependency: From: Identity Provider Management Server Feature 4.2.4 (org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.server.feature.group 4.2.4) To: org.wso2.carbon.stratos.common.server.feature.group [2.3.0,2.4.0) Cannot satisfy dependency: From: WSO2 Stratos - Common Composite Feature 2.2.2 (org.wso2.carbon.stratos.common.feature.group 2.2.2) To: org.wso2.carbon.stratos.common.server.feature.group [2.2.2] Cannot satisfy dependency: From: WSO2 Stratos - Common Core Feature 2.2.2 (org.wso2.carbon.stratos.common.server.feature.group 2.2.2) To: org.wso2.carbon.stratos.common.server.feature.jar [2.2.2] Cannot satisfy dependency: From: WSO2 Stratos - Common Core Feature 2.3.0 (org.wso2.carbon.stratos.common.server.feature.group 2.3.0) To: org.wso2.carbon.stratos.common.server.feature.jar [2.3.0]

Opening the Key Manager node on API Manager 1.7 shows that several sub nodes are duplicated for example:

```
 Key Manager        
 Api management Core    1.2.2   More Info.
 Api management Core    1.2.2   More Info.
 Application Authentication Framework Server    4.2.3   More Info.
 Application Authentication Framework Server    4.2.3   More Info.
 Application Management Server  4.2.0   More Info.
 BAM Message Tracer Handler Aggregate   4.2.3   More Info.
 BAM Message Tracer Handler Aggregate   4.2.3   More Info.
 BAM Message Tracer Handler Aggregate   4.2.3   More Info.
 Datasource Management Core     4.2.1   More Info
```

It seems that the suggested P2 repo http://dist.wso2.org/p2/carbon/releases/turing/ is a little borked.  Does anyone know of a different repo I can use or a subset of KM features to attempt installing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

P2 repo is fine..But there is an issue in our feature manager . We fixed it, but it requires a patch. For the time being, you can untick the Trusted Identity Provider Management feature from the Key Manager group and get the installation done. Anyway this issue is in AM 1.7.0 version. But you should be able to install AM 1.8.0 features without an issue.

Comment: Installing SP1 for the IS before installing the KeyManager feature avoids the issue.  Apparently the referenced fix is included in IS SP1.